# How to show list values in a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpfdatagrid

This might be a newbie question.

I want to show some information in a `DataGrid`. This does not have to be two-way binding, I only need to show the `DataGrid` as an output. The information is stored in a `List` that consists of `List(Of String)` items. The `List(Of String)` item being an entire row, where each `String` item within that list would go into its own column in the `DataGrid`.

So what would be the easiest way to do this?

I tried to do something like this:

Created the `DataGrid`:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="24,17,144,37">
    </DataGrid>
```

Created the "row" entry by adding some data to the first list:

```
    Dim MyEntryList As New List(Of String)

    MyEntryList.Add("SomeName")
    MyEntryList.Add("SomeInfo")
    MyEntryList.Add("SomeStuff")
```

Added the created "row" list to the encompassing list:

```
    Dim MyDataList As New List(Of List(Of String))

    MyDataList.Add(MyEntryList)
```

And finally tried to set the source of my `DataGrid`:

```
    Me.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = MyDataList
```

Instead of those strings, the `DataGrid` shows some numbers describing Capacity and Count:
[image]

How can I get it to show the contents of the lists?

Comment: That give count of your listvalues

Comment: You should consider, using a `DataTable` for this (with one way binding or readonly data grid)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How do you want to display List(Of List(Of String)) in the datagrid?

Comment: @Ganesh Let's say list A consists of multiple lists B that in turn consist of strings. That in mind, each list B holds data for each separate row of the datagrid. And each string in the list B would hold value for each column of the datagrid. List A would then be a collection of "rows".

Comment: Can you give a picture of what you want to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

You should try to build some objects or Datatable to populate the Datagrid. Refer the code below

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
    </DataGrid>

Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
        Class MainWindow

        Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

            Dim lst As New ObservableCollection(Of SomeObject)
            For index = 1 To 10
                Dim obj As New SomeObject
                obj.SomeName = "test" + index.ToString
                obj.SomeInfo = "info" + index.ToString
                lst.Add(obj)
            Next
            MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = lst
        End Sub
    End Class

    Class SomeObject
        Private name As String
        Public Property SomeName() As String
            Get
                Return name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                name = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private info As String
        Public Property SomeInfo() As String
            Get
                Return info
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                info = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. But I can't use this. For this I would have to know all the properties in advance (at compile time). Which I don't. I need to be able add items with previously unknown properties. For example, say I have object with "SomeName" and "SomeInfo", but then at runtime I need to able to add new property, that I didn't know of at compile time.